# Should my boiler be serviced annually?

Tags: boiler

I have a oil-fueled boiler that provides steam heat in the winter and hot water all year. Should I have it inspected and serviced annually? If so, what should such a service entail?

Answer (score 3):

One word......YES.

By a licensed burner technician.

Comment: The service will include both checks for efficient as well as safe operation (properly vented, no fractures in the firebox, etc.).   Ours also includes replacement of the oil filter, flue inspection, and nozzle cleaning.